# undefined error when creating table on phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

So I am trying to create this table that has 122 lines in it, there are no extra spaces in the names and I have filled out all the fields that I think I need, when I click to save a red box appears that says undefined... pictures below:

[image: part of my table]

The error:
[image: the error]

Comment: `122 lines` == `122 Columns`

Comment: Very annoying having put all that work in. But I suggest you write this out long hand, then going back and fixing bits is possible and easier

Comment: The other option is to keep fiddling with the rows you have attempted to create until you find the issue

Comment: If you have 122 columns, and you are almost allways using varchar (255) (I have seen one column of varchar(3000), i think you are maybe over the maximun row size (65535). Do you really need so many varchar(255) columns??

Comment: I dont know much about it, but all the videos I watch they use varchar is there a better one i could be using?

Comment: and to my understanding the "255" is the max amount of characters it can hold?

Comment: As I can imagine from your pictures, you may need to use date, int, double, timestamp data types, not allways varchar. I explain. If you are going to store a date, it is a very bad practice to store it in a varchar column. You should use the DATE data type. The same for numerical values and so on. If your string is going to be a name, it doesn't make sense to use varchar(255), because there are no names that use 255 characters. So use proper data types for your columns.